# Feature Product Extension structure

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I am Developing Feature Product Module so that i create all necessary Folders.

My Problem is

I Created **Namespace/Module/Block/Index.php**

```
 <?php   
class MPS_AllProduct_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

    /**
    * Get Feature Product 
    **/
    public function FeatureProduct(){
        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'feature','eq'=>'1'),))
            ->joinField('is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
            return $_productCollection;
    }
}
```

**my.phtml**

```
$featue = $this->FeatureProduct()
foreach($feature as $_product){
   echo $_product->getName();
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); // it's not working
echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') //it's not Working


}
```

So i check one extension that's is paid one they created folder called

**Block/Feature/List.php**

```
public function _getProductcollection(){
   /********
     code
   *******/
}
```

it's working fine what is the difference between these two which one is proper way

Comment: can you share you block file code?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your block file code

**From**

```
<?php   
class MPS_AllProduct_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   

    /**
    * Get Feature Product 
    **/
    public function FeatureProduct(){
        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'feature','eq'=>'1'),))
            ->joinField('is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
            return $_productCollection;
    }
}
```

**To**

```
<?php   
class MPS_AllProduct_Block_Index extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{   

    /**
    * Get Feature Product 
    **/
    public function FeatureProduct(){
        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'feature','eq'=>'1'),))
            ->joinField('is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
            return $_productCollection;
    }
}
```

**Second way:**

```
<?php   
class MPS_AllProduct_Block_Index extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{   

    /**
    * Get Feature Product 
    **/
    public function FeatureProduct()
    {
        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $_productCollection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());


        $_productCollection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($_productCollection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1);

        return $_productCollection;
    }
}
?>
```

**Third way:**

```
<?php   
class MPS_AllProduct_Block_Index extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected function FeatureProduct()
    {
        $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
                                ->addMinimalPrice()
                                ->addFinalPrice()
                                ->addTaxPercents()
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1)
                                ->addStoreFilter();

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        Mage::getModel('review/review')->appendSummary($collection);     

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok got it what is difference between that and this which means my question

Comment: yes it got pls try above code and let me know if any issues

Comment: also updated ans pls check

Comment: I can't able to see tool bar

Comment: need to add catalog/product_list_toolbar bock in layout file